# GNATBENCH 2.6 Install on Eclipse -- Missing File . . .

Tags: eclipse, ada

Tried installing the new academic version of GNATBENCH on Eclipse (Helios) today.
But it seems to find that a file is missing.

(I've notified AdaCore but I'd expect that it'll take a week for them to reply.)

Here's what she wrote :

*Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: GNATbench Integration with WindRiver Workbench 2.6.0.20111210 (com.adacore.gnatbench.windriver.feature.group 2.6.0.20111210)
  Missing requirement: GNATbench Integration with WindRiver Workbench 2.6.0.20111210 (com.adacore.gnatbench.windriver.feature.group 2.6.0.20111210) requires 'com.windriver.ide.ui 3.1.0' but it could not be found*

Anyone else with similar issue ?

Answer (score 1):

You didn't follow the Installation Instructions in the README.txt.

Please select the Eclipse Plugin only, not the WindRiver Workbench Plugin.

Comment: Yes ! Somehow, I'd missed that. Thanks, Oenone.

Comment: Heh. Was reading this thinking, "He's doing Ada development on VxWorks? Unusual, but cool."

Comment: No, I can't afford WindRiver stuff, which seems to be boxed with AdaCore tools in some sort of mutual arrangement between the companies.